# Error while building ghostscript on linux

Tags: build, installation, x11, ghostscript, configure

I'm trying to build Ghostscript (v 9.06) on my hosted linux box so I can manipulate PDF files.
Everything was going fine with `./configure` and `make`, but then I got the following error:

```
../gs/base/x_.h:135:29: error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory
```

After which I got a list of errors with funny `â` characters, looking like this:

```
../gs/base/gdevx.c:1138: error: âgx_device_Xâ has no member named âtextâ
```

What's the problem here, and what's the fix? I thought it was a symlink problem, so I checked where my X11 directory was and ran the following command:

```
 ln -s X11 /usr/include/X11
```

I ran `make` again but no difference. Any ideas?

### Edit

Here are the first few lines of the errors... the rest are all pretty much the same:

```
../gs/base/x_.h:135:29: error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory
../gs/base/x_.h:136:30: error: X11/StringDefs.h: No such file or directory
../gs/base/x_.h:137:25: error: X11/Shell.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../gs/base/gdevx.c:33:
../gs/base/gdevx.h:30: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âgdev_x_resourcesâ
../gs/base/gdevx.h:32: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âgdev_x_fallback_resourcesâ
../gs/base/gdevx.h:119: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âPixelâ
../gs/base/gdevx.c:217: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
../gs/base/gdevx.c:217: warning: (near initialization for âgs_x11_deviceâ)
../gs/base/gdevx.c:217: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
../gs/base/gdevx.c:217: warning: (near initialization for âgs_x11_deviceâ)
../gs/base/gdevx.c:217: error: extra brace group at end of initializer
../gs/base/gdevx.c:217: error: (near initialization for âgs_x11_deviceâ)
```

And the last few lines are:

```
make[2]: *** [obj/gdevx.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/ghostpdl-9.06/main'
make[1]: *** [pdl-product] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/ghostpdl-9.06/main'
make: *** [pcl] Error 2
```

Comment: As a minumum, you should first run `make clean`, then `./configure` and `make` again. -- Then, it also all depends how exactly your hoster has set up your environment. Are you in a *chroot*? Or is it a root server?

Comment: I used make clean too but no difference. No I'm not in chroot, I'm simply the root user on my VPS host server. I found that X11 is in the following directories: /etc/X11, /usr/include/X11, /usr/shared/X11, and one more directory (can't remember right now), but I chose /usr/include because it had the most contents and I believe I installed some things there earlier. Is this error even related to X11? Or is there some other problem? I'm editing my question to add a few more errors to it.

Comment: You probably need to install the development X11 package (may be called x11-devel or xlib-devel or something similar). Funny â characters signify a mismatch between your locale and your terminal's encoding. And remove that symbolic link.

Comment: Does your X11 directory indeed contain the `Intrinsic.h`, `StringDevs.h` and `Shell.h` header files? What Linux distribution is this?

Comment: Indeed it doesn't! None of them do. I guess I have to ensure correct installation of X11..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out I just didn't have the X package installed properly.

I ran

```
yum provides \*/Intrinsic.h
yum provides \*/StringDefs.h
yum provides \*/Shell.h
```

to find out where to get these files, and got

```
libXt-devel-1.0.7-1.el6.x86_64 : X.Org X11
```

for each of them. So I installed it:

```
yum install libXt-devel
```

then went back to my ghostscript directory, ran `make`, `./configure` and `make` again, and voila. It worked out.

Comment: If your hosted server doesn't run any working X11 applications, it makes no sense building Ghostscript to support X11 either. In this case you better do what KenS suggested: run `./configure --without-x` or `./configure --with-x=no`. If that works, you should also un-install the extra packages you added. You'd get a cleaner, leaner system this way.

Comment: I actually I do need X11 - I'm using wkhtmltopdf, which can't render certain fonts and arabic characters without X11. I take it Ghostscript doesn't need X11 for foreign fonts? I understand I could build it without X11, but are they not needed later?

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't need X11 for fonts. It needs X11 only if you want to display PDF or PostScript files on screen (`-sDEVICE=x11`, `-sDEVICE=x11alpha` etc.). `wkhtmltopdf` works differently -- it needs a virtual framebuffer at least (or X11) to do anything useful. (That's what I hate most about wkhtmltopdf, to be honest...)

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu users

> sudo apt-get install libxt-dev libxaw7-dev

Answer (score 2):

You don't need X11 to build Ghostscript, but you need to tell it not to. If you run `./configure --without-x` then the GS build will not include anything which relies on X (such as the display device) and won't look for the X libraries.

As long as you don't want to use the X11 or X11a devices that should work.